# Match data of two rows with different timestamp, into one row (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2017

I'm facing an issue with an SQL Server query.

You can see in the screenshot below a sample of the data in my database. The rows that contain as an attribute a big numeric value, are actually the events of a ticket that was read by the card reader.

There are also some rows that contain as an attribute a string like `Eticket result`. This event is generated when a ticket is invalid and the system shows the reason of the non validity of the ticket.

[image]

What I want to do is to create a new column (named as "reason") which will contain all the attributes that are like 'Eticket Result'. The thing is that all these attributes containing the 'ETICKET Result' must be matched with the correct ticket number. The time difference between the reason attribute and the non-valid ticket's timestamp, never exceeds 500 milliseconds.

In order to make it more understandable I'm giving you another screenshot below of what I want to do.

[image]

Is this possible to be done? I've been trying for hours and have created scripts that do not generate the correct result. If it helps you i give you below the query that i've made but doesn't show the correct data.

```
DECLARE @alarm_table TABLE (
 /*1*/server_timestamp     DATETIME ,
 /*2*/museum                 VARCHAR(255),
 /*3*/turnstile          VARCHAR(255),
 /*4*/entrance            VARCHAR(255),
 /*5*/cardnumber          VARCHAR(255),
 /*6*/result              VARCHAR(255),
 /*7*/reason              VARCHAR(255),
 /*8*/attributes             VARCHAR(255)

);

INSERT INTO @alarm_table
SELECT
  /*1*/servertimestamp,
  /*2*/hostname,
  /*3*/substring([hostname], PatIndex('%[0-9]%', [hostname]), len([hostname])),
  /*4*/substring(attributes, 31, 39),
  /*5*/attributes,
  /*6*/'NOT OK',
  /*7*/'',
  /*8*/attributes--substring(attributes, 70, 30)
FROM
  eventlog el
where
 (el.servertimestamp  BETWEEN '8/24/2018' AND DATEADD(dd, +1, '8/27/2019'))
 and (attributes like '%ticket %' and attributes like '%eticketing%' )
 and hostname <> 'tapaeos'
order by
  el.timestamp

 UPDATE @alarm_table
  SET cardnumber = substring(attributes, 31, 39)


  UPDATE @alarm_table
  SET result =  case
                   when 
                        (attributes like '%ticket 8%'
                        or attributes like '%ticket 9%'
                        or attributes like '%ticket 10%'
                        or attributes like '%ticket 11%' 
                        or attributes like '%ticket 12%' 
                        or attributes like '%ticket 13%' 
                        or attributes like '%ticket 14%' 
                        or attributes like '%knossos ticket 5%'
                        or attributes like '%knossos ticket 6%'
                        or attributes like '%knossos ticket 7%'
                        or attributes like '%klitys ticket 5%'
                        or attributes like '%klitys ticket 6%'
                        or attributes like '%klitys ticket 7%'
                        or attributes like '%olympieio ticket 5%'
                        or attributes like '%olympieio ticket 6%'
                        or attributes like '%olympieio ticket 7%'
                        ) 
                    then 'NOT OK'
                   else 'OK'
              end

  UPDATE @alarm_table
    SET reason = case
                    when result = 'NOT OK' then 
                    (SELECT top 1 attributes 
                     FROM eventlog 
                     WHERE DATEDIFF(second,servertimestamp,server_timestamp)<=1)
                   else ' '
              end

  UPDATE @alarm_table
    SET museum  = case
                 when museum like '%olymp%' then 'Olympieio'
                 when museum like '%knoss%' then 'Knossos'
                 when museum like '%sslope%' then 'Klitys'
                 when museum like '%acrop%' then 'Acropolis'
                end

  select
  server_timestamp,
  museum,
  turnstile,
  cardnumber,
  result,
  reason
 -- attributes
from
  @alarm_table



  order by server_timestamp desc
```

Your help will be much appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: Please show us a minimal example of sample data, as _text_, not as an image.  Your image data is very hard to read, and I think most folks won't be able to answer just based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select e1.*, e2.attributes reason
from (
    select *
    from eventlog
    where charindex('ETICKET Result', attributes) = 0
) e1 left join (
    select timestamp, attributes
    from eventlog
    where charindex('ETICKET Result', attributes) > 0
) e2 on abs(datediff(millisecond, e1.timestamp, e2.timestamp)) <= 500
```

In `e1` we query all records that are correct (without `ETICKET Reason`), in `e2` we select all incorrect records. Then we join both results on time difference in millisecodns.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'm running the query at this moment and i will let you know if it worked

Comment: @we_mor If answer has worked for you, please accept the answer (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Comment: Your answer helped a lot. It'd didn't get the correct results, but it helped me reconstruct the query to a new one that works. Thank you for your help, i'll mark it as accepted.